# How to resolve "the attribute error" for selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python 3.7 on windows 8.I have already installed the selenium as well as chromedriver.

I have tried adding path for chromedriver

```
(browser=webdriver.Chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe"))
```

also added the path in system variables (\F:\chromedriver.exe)

```
import webbrowser,selenium,sys
from selenium import webdriver

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    email=''.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    print("Enter the email address:")
    email=input()


browser=webdriver.Chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://gmail.com")
```

While the surprising part is I am getting output through python shell (web page is opening) but I am getting Attribute error while running through command prompt.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtgHM.png Please see the error window on this link.

Comment: can you add the full error?

Comment: Yes .. I have added the link

Comment: You should copy paste the actual error this can help future users and it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with importing...

You are importing `selenium` twice...

try removing unnecessary imports:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    email=''.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    print("Enter the email address:")
    email=input()


browser=webdriver.Chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://gmail.com")
```

Hope this helps you!